# .net core integration tests resolve scoped services #2

Tags: entity-framework-core, integration-testing

I'm trying to get instance of scoped service, but calling `appFactory.Server.Services.GetRequiredService<T>()` ends up with 'missing scope' error and `appFactory.Server.Services.CreateScope().ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<T>()` returns a new instance of service T that is not same as instance that is used in my server endpoint...

Some code to better understanding - server

```cs
// server site code, ServerUserEndpoints.MapEndpoints is called between 
// `var app = builder.Build();` and `app.Run();` calls ...

internal sealed class UserManager : UserManager<User> { ... }

internal static class ServerUserEndpoints 
{
    public static void MapEndpoints(IEndpointRouteBuilder builder) 
    {
        builder.MapPost("/user/{userId}/GenerateTwoFactorToken", GenerateTwoFactorTokenAsync);
    }

    internal static async Task<IResult> GenerateTwoFactorTokenAsync(
         [FromServices] UserManager userManager,
         [FromRoute]    string      userId,
         [FromBody]     string      tokenProvider)
    {
         var user = await userManager.FindByIdAsync(userId);

         if (user == null) 
         {
             return Results.NotFound();
         }

         var result = await userManager.GenerateTwoFactorTokenAsync(user, tokenProvider);

         return Results.Ok(result);
     }
}
```

Client:

```cs
// client code (different classlib, no access to UserManager)
// code simply calls server endpoint & translate response
public sealed class ClientUserEndpoints 
{
    private readonly HttpClient _HttpClient;

    public UserEndpoints(HttpClient httpClient) 
    {
        _HttpClient = httpClient;
    }
    
    public async Task<string> GenerateTwoFactorTokenAsync(string userId, string tokenProvider) 
    {
        var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, $"/user/{userId}/GenerateTwoFactorToken");
        request.Content = JsonContent.Create(tokenProvider);

        var result = await _HttpClient.SendAsync(request);

        result.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

        return (await result.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<string>())!;
    }
}
```

And finally test code (references both client & server class libs):

```cs
// base class for all test classes
public class IdentityDbContextTestsBase : IDisposable 
{
    private readonly WebApplicationFactory _Application;

    protected IdentityDbContextTestsBase() 
    {
        _Application = new WebApplicationFactory();
        HttpClient   = _Application.CreateClient();
    }

    public IServiceScope? Scope { get; private set; }
    public HttpClient HttpClient { get; }

    public void Dispose() 
    {
        HttpClient.Dispose();
        Scope?.Dispose();
        _Application.Dispose();
    }

    [MemberNotNull(nameof(Scope))]
    public async Task<IIdentityDbContext> Initialize() 
    {
        Scope = _Application.Server.Services.CreateScope();

        var context = Scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IIdentityDbContext>();
        await context.Database.EnsureDeletedAsync();
        await context.Database.EnsureCreatedAsync();

        return context;
    }
}

// and test class ...
public class UserEndpointsTests : IdentityDbContextTestsBase 
{
    [Fact]
    public async Task GenerateTwoFactorTokenAsync_Success() 
    {
        // Arrange
        var context   = await Initialize();
        var user      = context.Users.First(o => o.NormalizedUserName == "SWAGGER");
        var endpoints = new ClientUserEndpoints(HttpClient);

        // this userManager instance is not same as parameter in ServerUserEndpoints.GenerateTwoFactorTokenAsync method
        var userManager = Scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<UserManager>();

        var tokenProvider = Substitute.For<IUserTwoFactorTokenProvider<User>>();
        tokenProvider.GenerateAsync("FOO", userManager, user).Returns(Task.FromResult("TOKEN"));

        userManager.RegisterTokenProvider("tokenProvider", tokenProvider);

        // Act
        // this will throw "No IUserTwoFactorTokenProvider<TUser> named 'tokenProvider' is registered."
        var result = await endpoints.GenerateTwoFactorTokenAsync(user.Id, "tokenProvider");

        // Assert
        result.Should().NotBeNull();
    }
}
```

PS: I know about [.net core integration tests resolve scoped services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64856573/net-core-integration-tests-resolve-scoped-services) but that didn't work for me ...

PPS: my other tests that don't need to register token provider to user manager works - for example this one (same test class):

```cs
public async Task AddClaim_Success() 
{
    // Arrange
    var context = await Initialize();
    var user    = context.Users.First(o => o.NormalizedUserName == "SWAGGER");

    var endpoints = new UserEndpoints(HttpClient);

    // Act
    var result = await endpoints.AddClaimAsync(user.Id, new ClaimDataObject { Type = "type", Value = "value" });

    // Assert
    result.Should().BeTrue();

    var userClaims = context.UserClaims.AsNoTracking();
    userClaims.Should().HaveCount(1);
    userClaims.Should().Contain(o => o.UserId == user.Id && o.ClaimType == "type" && o.ClaimValue == "value");
}
```